# Can you figure out why my code is giving me an IndexOutOfBounds error?

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm currently trying to populate a SQL database (for an assignment) through Python. I have created a function to help me do that.
When I run the function, however, I receive a 'List index out of range" Index error. I would appreciate all and any help!

I have tried reverting to some old code, but it doesn't help with the current problem.

As I understand that there is apparently no "field[1]" (otherwise I wouldn't be receiving this error) I have tried printing each step of my function as it occurs... only to discover that I can, in fact, print the elusive value, but still receive an error about that line?

I have included all the code I believe to be relevant, however, if you think I must be missing something, feel free to contact me. Thank you very much!

```
def populateStudentTable(textFile,targetTable):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    numRecs = 0
    dataRecs = []
    textRec = textFile.readline()
    while textRec != "":
        numRecs += 1
        field = textRec.split(", ")
        print(field)
        print(field[0])
        print(field[1])
        textRec = textFile.readline()
```

When I run the program, it prints the second item in the list: field[1]
But then after that, it gives me an error...

```
['VENNGEOR', 'Georgia', 'Venna', '12', 'Maths', '8596746234']
VENNGEOR
Georgia
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "h:\Digital Solutions\VS Code\Dev.py", line 22, in <module>
numRecs = populateStudentTable(textFile,"tblMentor")
File "h:\Digital Solutions\VS Code\Dev.py", line 14, in 
populateStudentTable:print(field[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

After reading some comments and doing some more debugging of my own, I discovered that "buran" was correct. I had simply left some empty lines and was trying to run a loop on an empty line.

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear. in file `Dev.py`, in function `populateStudentTable`, a call to `print(field[1])` caused and `IndexError`, meaning  `field[1]` is out of bounds

Comment: check the content of the file you are reading from. I would guess the problem is you have empty line(s) at the end of the file and what you show is the last real row with data. Then the empty line with new line line char would throw an error.

Comment: There isn't really much more we can do right now, the error says that `field[1]` is out of bounds. We don't know the content of the file or the rest of the code. Now that you know that this function raises an exception, Your best move would be to set up a breakpoint and debug it step by step.

Comment: can you provide what your program prints just before the error?? I bet it says something like `[ 'blah' ]`, `blah` and then your `IndexError`, since the list `[ 'blah' ]` contains only one element =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line in `textFile` did not contain the number of `,` characters you expect. When you do `field = textRec.split(", ")` then resulting `field` might not have 3 elements as you expect if there was less than two `,` in the line.

Examine the content of your file or simply instead of printing elements of `field` print `field` itself. This will make it easier for you to understand where you got this wrong.

Also note you are splitting by ", " (not ","), so be aware of situations like this may also result in your error:

```py
>>> foo = "a,b,c, d"
>>> foo.split(", ")
['a,b,c', 'd']
```

Comment: Hey Greg0ry
I just checked the content of my file... and I had empty spaces after the list... so it was trying to run another loop... so it was really just a problem in the file from which I was importing my values.